# Inherent time in jprofiler

Tags: jprofiler

Consider the below method template:

```
methodA()
{
 Print (abc); // Instruction 1
 Calculate(a+b+c); // Instruction 2

 Call methodB();// Instruction 3
 Call methodC();// Instruction 4

 Print(abcd); // Instruction 5
 for(; ;)  // Instruction 6
 {
              . .. 
 }
}
```

Inherent time for methodA() in JProfiler shows the total time taken by methodA() alone. Is this inherent time the sum of CPU time + I/O wait time or is it just CPU time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The time type depends on the thread state selector in the top-right corner of the call tree view. If it is set to "Runnable", the displayed times measure the time when the CPU was in the runnable state. If it set to "All states", it includes I/O, waiting and blocking.

Answer (score 0):

As per this page http://resources.ej-technologies.com/jprofiler/help/doc/index.html

> The inherent time is defined as the total time of a method minus the
>   time of its child nodes.